# Android ViewModel additional arguments

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-components

Is there a way to pass additional argument to my custom `AndroidViewModel` constructor except Application context.
Example:

```kotlin
    public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        private final LiveData<List<MyObject>> myObjectList;
        private AppDatabase appDatabase;

        public MyViewModel(Application application, String param) {
            super(application);
            appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());
            
            myObjectList = appDatabase.myOjectModel().getMyObjectByParam(param);
        }
    }
```

And when I want to user my custom `ViewModel` class I use this code in my fragment:

```kotlin
    MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class)
```

So I don't know how to pass additional argument `String param` into my custom `ViewModel`. I can only pass Application context, but not additional arguments. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Edit: I've added some code. I hope it's better now.

Comment: add more details and code

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There is no error message. I simply don't know where to set arguments for constructor as ViewModelProvider is used for creating AndroidViewModel objects.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

You need to have a factory class for your ViewModel.

```java
public class MyViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private Application mApplication;
    private String mParam;


    public MyViewModelFactory(Application application, String param) {
        mApplication = application;
        mParam = param;
    }


    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new MyViewModel(mApplication, mParam);
    }
}
```

And when instantiating the view model, you do like this:

```java
MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, new MyViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), "my awesome param")).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

For kotlin, you may use delegated property:

```kotlin
val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels { MyViewModelFactory(getApplication(), "my awesome param") }
```

There's also another new option - to implement `HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory` and override `getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()` with the instantiation of your factory and then you would call `ViewModelProvider(this)` or `by viewModels()` without the factory.

Comment: Does every `ViewModel` class need its ViewModelFactory?

Comment: No, it's a factory, so it's up to you which `ViewModel` will you instantiate. You can have one factory for 2 `ViewModels` and e.g. some sort of flag to recognise which `ViewModel` will be returned from the `create()` method.

Comment: but every `ViewModel` could/will have different DI. How would you know which instance return on the `create()` method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? If you want to use it with DI then you need to do different implementation which would inject requested parameters. If you don't and just want to share one factory among several different viewModels, you can distinguish them based on the `modelClass` parameter which is passed from the `get(MyViewModel.class)` method

Comment: Your ViewModel will be recreated after change orientation. Your cant create factory every time.

Comment: That's not true. New `ViewModel` creation prevents method `get()`. Based on documentation: "Returns an existing ViewModel or creates a new one in the scope (usually, a fragment or an activity), associated with this ViewModelProvider."
see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html#get(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)

Comment: `MyViewModelFactory` should just extend `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Comment: You are right, although it works for both variants (I'll edit the answer).

Comment: It causes the 'unchecked cast' warning. Any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately only solution I know is to suppress the warning for the class/method.

Comment: how about using `return modelClass.cast(new MyViewModel(mApplication, mParam))` to get rid of the warning

Comment: `ViewModelProvides` is now deprecated!

Comment: If we are sharing the same view model with two fragment and only one has the fields to initialize it how could the second fragment create the same view model to access the data

the first fragment needs to pass data to the second fragment via the view model

Comment: HI  this is very nice post but can you please help me  what we need to pass Application ?

Answer (score 57):

## Implement with Dependency Injection

This is more advanced and better for production code.

**Dagger2**, Square's [AssistedInject](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject#usage-with-dagger-2) offers a production-ready implementation for ViewModels that can inject necessary components such as a repository that handles network and database requests. It also allows for the manual injection of arguments/parameters in the activity/fragment. Here's a concise outline of the [steps to implement](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H4eCai4HROxWGxFi2LXcgaAgTdrW4hkldHHrFoRV8eI/edit#bookmark=id.r187xkjfk1c3) with code Gists based on Gabor Varadi's detailed post, [Dagger Tips](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-tips-leveraging-assistedinjection-to-inject-viewmodels-with-savedstatehandle-and-93fe009ad874).

**[Dagger Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)**, is the next generation solution, in alpha as of 7/12/20, offering the same use case with a simpler setup once the library is in release status.

## Implement with [Lifecycle 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_220_3) in Kotlin

### Passing Arguments/Parameters

```kotlin
// Override ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory to create the ViewModel (VM).
class SomeViewModelFactory(private val someString: String): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = SomeViewModel(someString) as T
} 

class SomeViewModel(private val someString: String) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        //TODO: Use 'someString' to init process when VM is created. i.e. Get data request.
    }
}

class Fragment: Fragment() {
    // Create VM in activity/fragment with VM factory.
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels { SomeViewModelFactory("someString") } 
}
```

### Enabling SavedState with Arguments/Parameters

```kotlin
class SomeViewModelFactory(
    private val owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    private val someString: String) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, null) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, state: SavedStateHandle) =
            SomeViewModel(state, someString) as T
}

class SomeViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle, private val someString: String) : ViewModel() {
    val feedPosition = state.get<Int>(FEED_POSITION_KEY).let { position ->
        if (position == null) 0 else position
    }
        
    init {
        //TODO: Use 'someString' to init process when VM is created. i.e. Get data request.
    }
        
     fun saveFeedPosition(position: Int) {
        state.set(FEED_POSITION_KEY, position)
    }
}

class Fragment: Fragment() {
    // Create VM in activity/fragment with VM factory.
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels { SomeViewModelFactory(this, "someString") } 
    private var feedPosition: Int = 0
     
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        someViewModel.saveFeedPosition((contentRecyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
                .findFirstVisibleItemPosition())
    }    
        
    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        feedPosition = someViewModel.feedPosition
    }
}
```

Comment: While overriding create in the factory I get a warning saying Unchecked cast 'ItemViewModel to T'

Comment: That warning has not been an issue for me so far. However, I will look into it further when I refactor the ViewModel factory to inject it using Dagger rather than creating an instance of it via the fragment.

Comment: I don't get why people see the need post unrelated answer. Question never asked for DI library implementation

Answer (score 19):

For one factory shared between multiple different view models I'd extend mlyko's answer like this:

```java
public class MyViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
    private Application mApplication;
    private Object[] mParams;

    public MyViewModelFactory(Application application, Object... params) {
        mApplication = application;
        mParams = params;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == ViewModel1.class) {
            return (T) new ViewModel1(mApplication, (String) mParams[0]);
        } else if (modelClass == ViewModel2.class) {
            return (T) new ViewModel2(mApplication, (Integer) mParams[0]);
        } else if (modelClass == ViewModel3.class) {
            return (T) new ViewModel3(mApplication, (Integer) mParams[0], (String) mParams[1]);
        } else {
            return super.create(modelClass);
        }
    }
}
```

And instantiating view models:

```java
ViewModel1 vm1 = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(getApplication(), "something")).get(ViewModel1.class);
ViewModel2 vm2 = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(getApplication(), 123)).get(ViewModel2.class);
ViewModel3 vm3 = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new MyViewModelFactory(getApplication(), 123, "something")).get(ViewModel3.class);
```

With different view models having different constructors.

Comment: I don't recommend this way because couple of reasons:
1) parameters in factory are not type safe - this way you can break your code on runtime. Always try to avoid this approach when possible

2) checking view model types is not really OOP way of doing things. Since the ViewModels are casted  to base type, again you can break code during runtime without any warning during compilation.. In this case I'd suggest using default android factory and pass the parameters to already instantiated view model.

Comment: @mlyko Sure, these are all valid objections and own method(s) to set up the viewmodel data is always an option. But sometimes you want to make sure that viewmodel has been initialized, hence the use of constructor. Otherwise you must yourself handle situation "viewmodel not initialized yet". For example if viewmodel has methods that return LivedData and observers are attached to that in various View lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 12):

Based on @vilpe89 the above Kotlin solution for AndroidViewModel cases

```kotlin
class ExtraParamsViewModelFactory(
    private val application: Application,
    private val myExtraParam: String
): ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = 
            SomeViewModel(application, myExtraParam) as T
}
```

Then a fragment can initiate the viewModel as

```kotlin
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    
    // ...

    private val myViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels {
        ExtraParamsViewModelFactory(this.requireActivity().application, "some string value")
    }

    // ...

}
```

And then the actual ViewModel class

```kotlin
class SomeViewModel(application: Application, val myExtraParam:String) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    // ...
}
```

Or in some suitable method ...

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(...){
    // ...
    val myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ExtraParamsViewModelFactory(this.requireActivity().application, "some string value")).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The question asks how to pass arguments/parameters without using context which the above does not follow: _Is there a way to pass additional argument to my custom AndroidViewModel constructor except Application context?_

Comment: This is giving a warning for an unchecked cast to type `T`, am I missing something or is this a non-issue?

Comment: About the unchecked cast. This is how it's handled in some Google developer training code: 
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/0905d0e307ef457a4c37511a542edfe3bdb4d2a3/MADSkillsNavigationSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/samples/donuttracker/ViewModelFactory.kt#L22
and:
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/5dc4c4a330da24c7d32c47a601125691cace80e2/MarsRealEstateFinal/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/marsrealestate/detail/DetailViewModelFactory.kt#L30
The first example shows, that the context its not needed

Answer (score 5):

The proper way is to use a dependency injection framework such as [Dagger hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android). If not using a DI framework, then do it with ViewModelFactory.

**With Dagger Hilt:**

A ViewModel with parameters

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myRepository: MyRepository,
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() { ... }
```

A Repository

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val myRemoteDataSource: MyDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) { ... }
```

A Module for providing the dependencies/parameters so they can be injected into repositories and ViewModels.

```
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
@Module
object MyProvideModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideMyDataSource(@ApplicationContext context: Context): MyDataSource {
        //code to create MyDataSource... 
        return MyDataSource(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideCoroutineDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher {
        return Dispatchers.IO
    }
}
```

A module for binding the repository

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
interface RepositoryModules {
    @Binds
    fun provideMyRepository(repository: MyRepository): MyRepository
}
```

Initiating Dagger hilt with the application with the @HiltAndroidApp annotation.

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

}
```

Getting the ViewModel in activities

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
  // Other code...
}
```

Getting the ViewModel in fragments

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
  private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
  // Other code...
}
```

**With ViewModelFactory:**

A ViewModel with parameter messageDataStore, where MessageDataStore is a DataStore class or it can be anything else that you want to pass into the ViewModel.

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val messageDataStore: MessageDataStore,
): ViewModel() { ... }
```

The ViewModel factory class for creating ViewModels

```
/**
 * Factory for all ViewModels.
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class ViewModelFactory constructor(
    private val messageDataStore: MessageDataStore,
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
        key: String,
        modelClass: Class<T>,
        handle: SavedStateHandle
    ) = with(modelClass) {
        when {
            isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java) ->
                MyViewModel(messageDataStore)
            else ->
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: ${modelClass.name}")
        }
    } as T
}
```

The application class for creating the dependencies/parameters

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    val messageDataStore: MessageDataStore
        get() = MessageDataStore.getInstance(this)

}
```

Extension functions for getting the factory class in activities and fragments, MyExt.kt

```
fun AppCompatActivity.getViewModelFactory(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): ViewModelFactory {
    val messageDataStore = (applicationContext as MyApp).messageDataStore
    return ViewModelFactory(messageDataStore, this, savedInstanceState)
}

fun Fragment.getViewModelFactory(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): ViewModelFactory {
    val messageDataStore = (requireContext().applicationContext as MyApp).messageDataStore
    return ViewModelFactory(messageDataStore, this.requireActivity(), savedInstanceState)
}
```

Getting the ViewMode in activities

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel
  // Other code...

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val vm by viewModels<MyViewModel> { getViewModelFactory(savedInstanceState) }
    myViewModel = vm
    // Other code...
  }
}
```

Getting the ViewModel in Fragments.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    //Other code...

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
      val vm by activityViewModels<MyViewModel> { getViewModelFactory(savedInstanceState) }
      myViewModel = vm
      //Other code...
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding Hilt to a multi-module project is not very straightforward. I managed to setup that way but didn't like adding the "not transitive" dependencies to all modules. This time I will go with the Factory class approach. Thanks for sharing both.

Answer (score 4):

I made it a class in which the already created object is passed.

```
private Map<String, ViewModel> viewModelMap;

public ViewModelFactory() {
    this.viewModelMap = new HashMap<>();
}

public void add(ViewModel viewModel) {
    viewModelMap.put(viewModel.getClass().getCanonicalName(), viewModel);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ViewModel> viewModel : viewModelMap.entrySet()) {
        if (viewModel.getKey().equals(modelClass.getCanonicalName())) {
            return (T) viewModel.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then

```
ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory = new ViewModelFactory();
viewModelFactory.add(new SampleViewModel(arg1, arg2));
SampleViewModel sampleViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(SampleViewModel.class);
```

Comment: We should have a ViewModelFactory for every ViewModel to pass the parameters to the constructor ??

Comment: No. Only one ViewModelFactory for all ViewModels

Comment: Is there any reason for using canonical name as the hashMap key ? Can i use class.simpleName ?

Comment: Yes, but you must make sure there are no duplicate names

Comment: Is this the recommended style of writing the code ? You came up with this code on your own or you read it in android docs ?

Comment: I invented it myself

Comment: Ok, then what is the android docs recommended way of doing it  ? Any idea ? For now,  i'm following your answer, as i don't have any other better solution.

Answer (score 1):

(KOTLIN) My solution uses little bit of Reflection.

Lets say you don't want to create the same looking Factory class every time you create new ViewModel class which needs some arguments. You can accomplish this via Reflection.

For example you would have two different Activities:

```kotlin
class Activity1 : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val args = Bundle().apply { putString("NAME_KEY", "Vilpe89") }
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, ViewModelWithArgumentsFactory(args))
            .get(ViewModel1::class.java)
    }
}

class Activity2 : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val args = Bundle().apply { putInt("AGE_KEY", 29) }
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders
            .of(this, ViewModelWithArgumentsFactory(args))
            .get(ViewModel2::class.java)
    }
}
```

And ViewModels for those Activities:

```kotlin
class ViewModel1(private val args: Bundle) : ViewModel()

class ViewModel2(private val args: Bundle) : ViewModel()
```

Then the magic part, Factory class's implementation:

```kotlin
class ViewModelWithArgumentsFactory(private val args: Bundle) : NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        try {
            val constructor: Constructor<T> = modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Bundle::class.java)
            return constructor.newInstance(args)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e, "Could not create new instance of class %s", modelClass.canonicalName)
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, since the caller of the `ViewModel` and the `ViewModel` itself run in different coroutines, it is more natural and convenient to pass data between them using `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel`:

```
class NewViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val newData: MutableLiveData<Service.DataEntry?> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Service.DataEntry?>().also {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val channel = Service.ParamChannel   // type Channel<Params>
                val params = channel.receive()
                it.value = Service.postSomething(params)
            }
        }
    }

    fun getData(): LiveData<Service.DataEntry?> {
        return newData
    }
}

// Calling code:
val model: NewViewModel by viewModels()
model.getData().observe(this) { newData ->
    if (newData != null) {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
runBlocking {
    Service.ParamChannel.send(theParams)
}
```

This is part of working code which I anonymized for demo purposes.

Answer (score 1):

this is the most clean way

```
class ImagesViewModel(application: Application,private val fragmentType: FragmentType) : AndroidViewModel(application) {


class Factory(private val application: Application, private val fragmentType: FragmentType) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        ImagesViewModel(application, fragmentType) as T
}
```

}

and create instance

```
         val viewModel: ImagesViewModel by viewModels { ImagesViewModel.Factory(requireActivity().application ,fragmentType) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that should make doing this more straightforward and way cleaner, no multibindings or factory boilerplate needed, while working seamlessly with ViewModel arguments that can be provided as dependencies by Dagger:
https://github.com/radutopor/ViewModelFactory

```
@ViewModelFactory
class UserViewModel(@Provided repository: Repository, userId: Int) : ViewModel() {

    val greeting = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        val user = repository.getUser(userId)
        greeting.value = "Hello, $user.name"
    }    
}
```

In the view:

```
class UserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var userViewModelFactory2: UserViewModelFactory2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user)
        appComponent.inject(this)

        val userId = intent.getIntExtra("USER_ID", -1)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, userViewModelFactory2.create(userId))
            .get(UserViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.greeting.observe(this, Observer { greetingText ->
            greetingTextView.text = greetingText
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not do it like this:

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<MyObject>> myObjectList;
    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private boolean initialized = false;

    public MyViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public initialize(String param){
      synchronized ("justInCase") {
         if(! initialized){
          initialized = true;
          appDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this.getApplication());
          myObjectList = appDatabase.myOjectModel().getMyObjectByParam(param);
    }
   }
  }
}
```

and then use it like this in two steps:

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProvider.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class)
myViewModel.initialize(param)
```

Comment: The whole point of putting parameters in the constructor is to initialize the view model only _once_. With your implementation, if you call `myViewModel.initialize(param)` in `onCreate` of the activity, for example, it can be called multiple times on the same `MyViewModel` instance as the user rotates the device.

Comment: @Sanlok Lee  Ok. How about adding a condition to the function to prevent initializing when unnecessary. Check my edited answer.