# How to pass parameters of more than one API Methods to ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, viewmodelfactory

I'm using ViewModelFactory to pass API method input parameters to my ViewModel Class as someone told [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46704702/6444297), but my question is what should I do to send parameters of more than one API method to ViewModel?

Is it OK to call more than one API method in a ViewModel or I should create a ViewModel for every API Method?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is what should I do to send parameters of more than one
> API method to ViewModel?

It would make more sense to use dependency injection. ([Dagger Hilt - ViewModel](https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model.html))

> Is it OK to call more than one API method in a ViewModel or I should
> create a ViewModel for every API Method?

I recommend using Repository Pattern.

Comment: I have Repository, now. I save data to database using Room ORM, but I should tell repository that I need to `getSomething()`, give me from db or API.

Comment: Yes. By creating a new function, you can continue api service operations from here.
The point you need to pay attention to. You add the relevant dependencies.

Comment: about passing parametrers... is there any solution without using di?

Comment: `is there any solution without using di?` of course, using a dependency injection framework or any library won't do something you can't do yourself