# Using ViewModel default constructor Versus via ViewModelProvider class?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

I have an Android `ViewModel`

```
class MyVM: ViewModel()
```

In my activity, I can create an instance of `MyVM` using either:

```
val viewModel = MyVM()
```

or using:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyVM::class.java)
```

They both work as expected. My question is what are the main differences between the two

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#lifecycle

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283981/android-viewmodel-additional-arguments) This has been answered here

Comment: This has been answered here [android-viewmodel-additional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283981/android-viewmodel-additional-arguments)

Comment: If you directly call the constructor instead of going through the ViewModelProvider, it will not be cached and survive screen rotations or Fragment restoration. It will not go through its lifecycle functions. There would be no point in making it a subclass of ViewModel at all because you wouldn’t be using any of the ViewModel features.